# a more formal synonym of "a drop in the bucket"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request

I'm writing a classroom research paper and this is the sentence I'm struggling with:

> "...From this point of view, *although just a drop in the bucket*, the present research helps form a solid conviction on the best way to approach SLA vocabulary instruction."

I think *a drop in the bucket* is not appropriate in this context. Is there a formal way to say this? Preferably keep the idiomatic aspect in mind.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you looking for a word like "insignificant", or a common phrase that is more formal?

Comment: @fixer1234 I want to use an expression or idiom to give the sentence some color but if there isn't anything in particular then a more formal word is better.

Comment: You're making the point that it actually has value, though small.  Perhaps something along the lines of "although only a small contribution,..."

Comment: helps forming...  ??

Comment: @TRomano Correct. that was a mistake. in my comment i used _form_ or _to form_ :) i'll edit that right away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [a drop in the bucket](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/a+drop+in+the+bucket)
>   An insufficient or inconsequential amount in comparison with what is required.
>   (The Free Dictionary)

There are a few words to choose from: *minute*, *minuscule*, and their various synonyms. But I think the definition above gives a good possibility:

> [insufficient](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/insufficient)
>   not enough in amount, strength, or quality; less than is needed:
>   *There was insufficient evidence, so we had to find him not guilty.*
>   (Cambridge Dictionary)

This implies that the current research is not enough to prove that it's the best approach, but that the research does suggest it.

Another possibility is *incomplete*:

> [incomplete](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/incomplete)
>   lacking some parts, or not finished:
>   *The polls have closed but the results of the election are still incomplete.*
>   (Cambridge Dictionary)

This implies that the research is somehow not finished, but that there is enough to suggest that this method is best.

Comment: If I want to use your suggestion in my sentence I think i have to change it into an adverb: "From this point of view, although **insufficiently**, the present research helps..." Am I right?

Comment: "inconsequential" is probably the best word in your answer, that's actually the meaning of the expression.  As a phrase: "although of little consequence,..."

Comment: @Yuri Interesting. It's possible. My version emphasizes that the research is insufficient/"not enough", but it's good enough to use; whereas I think your version emphasizes that the research suggests that it is best, but "poorly"/insufficiently. By the way, I assume in your post that you mean my version. Please clarify if I have assumed incorrectly.

Comment: @fixer1234 The dictionary states insufficient *or* inconsequential. I proposed insufficient because inconsequential to me implies that the research had no value.

Comment: You're right.  It dawned on me that "drop in the bucket" probably isn't a good starting point for exactly that reason.

Comment: "The research is insufficient to help form a conviction"  _vs._ "The reasearch helps insufficiently to form a conviction" I think I mean the second :-) interesting. to be honest, i haven't thought about it that way either. I guess version one is kind of negative and _too_ humble :-) Thank you + 1 no matter if there will be a better answer later, i liked this conversation. Pretty informative

Answer (score 2):

In British English the expression [a drop in the ocean](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/a-drop-in-the-ocean) is more widely used... and IMHO sounds more formal.

This [NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=drop%20in%20the%20ocean%2Cdrop%20in%20the%20bucket&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdrop%20in%20the%20ocean%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdrop%20in%20the%20bucket%3B%2Cc0) shows the relative frequencies in British English.

Answer (score 0):

You could say

... although it is only a start, ...

... although it is only a step in the right direction, ...

... although it is only a beginning, ...